# Subshell notation for hydrogen cation?

Tags: atoms, notation, ions, molecules

Looking at $s$,$p$,$d$ configuration for atoms & ions: Since a hydrogen cation $H^+$ has no electron, how would the subshell notation be written?  My best estimate would be $1s^0$.

Comment: What would the subshell be if we assume a muon not being there?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring for a moment the fact that you're describing an electronic configuration with *no electrons*, yes that's probably fine and I'm sure people will understand it. But then you could just write nothing and get the same information across. Moreover, it's not like a bare proton is waiting there with an empty $1s$ orbital that can accept electrons, more that an electron can enter into an aufbau bound state with the first two quantum numbers being $1$ and $s$. As such, it's not terribly meaningful to talk about a $1s^{0}$ configuration.

Answer (score -2):

A little correction. An ionized atom's energy level is probably infinite.

So IMHO the notion should be *inf* s0.